# Paypal ConnectionManagerError

Tags: paypal

ConnectionManagerError: Cannot connect to db FININST, pip fininst_occ_host 1:10.72.108.212:33465: socket. Gave up after 2 ConnectionManager tries. Backtrace: PPException::PPException(String const&) ConnectionManagerError::ConnectionManagerError(String const&) ConnectionManager::connect_pip(SmartPointer const&, OCCHost const&, unsigned) ConnectionManager::get_connection(OCCHost const&, bool, bool, bool) TransactionHandler::prepare_sql(char const, OCCHost const&, char const, unsigned, bool)

Comment: I had this error today when using the test payment gateway

Comment: Had the same error today, I was totally not able to process my test payments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's somehow related to Paypal session that is still logged-in. What helped me with that error was to click Log out on Paypal error page and then, test the payment again.